# ionic serve on iOS 14 device. Error "Invalid Service"

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, xcode12

After upgrading an iPhone6s to iOS 14 and Xcode to the latest version, I am unable to serve the app.

The error stack is as following

```sh
Error: InvalidService
    at LockdownProtocolReader.parseBody (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/native-run/node_modules/node-ioslib/dist/protocol/lockdown.js:35:19)
    at LockdownProtocolReader.onData (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/native-run/node_modules/node-ioslib/dist/protocol/protocol.js:52:40)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:212:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23)
```

running with `--verbose` shows the origin of the error

```sh
client:lockdownd startService: com.apple.debugserver +898ms
  protocol:lockdown socket write: {"Request":"StartService","Service":"com.apple.debugserver"} +206ms
  protocol:lockdown Response: {"Error":"InvalidService","Request":"StartService","Service":"com.apple.debugserver"} +6ms
  native-run Caught fatal error: Error: InvalidService
```

my serve script is

```sh
ionic cordova run iOS --l --debug --device --address=0.0.0.0 --sourceMap=true
```

Ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.11.8 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.2.2
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.900.7
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 9.1.4
   @angular/cli                  : 9.1.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : ios 5.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 20 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res                          : not installed
   native-run (update available: 1.1.0) : 1.0.0

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.10.0
   ios-sim    : 8.0.2
   NodeJS     : v12.18.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.14.5
   OS         : macOS Catalina
   Xcode      : Xcode 12.0 Build version 12A7209
```

what I have tried so far.

- reboot Mac
- reboot iPhone
- make sure latest iOS/Mac/Xcode version is installed
- clean build

running on emulator is working fine btw.
I can also perform `ionic build` and run via Xcode on the device.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I think it is connected to this error, which occurs first:
`iPhoneConnect: Failed _shouldMakeReadyForDevelopment check even though device is not locked by passcode.`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I solved it by updating `native-run` to 1.2.1 (see https://github.com/ionic-team/native-run/issues/60, support for iOS 14 has been added in 1.2.0 on 2020-09-28):

```
npm i -g native-run@latest
```

Comment: since this versions contains the actual fix instead of a workaround (switching to Cordova run), I will mark it as the current accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Got the same error while i was using native-run.

So i tried to run it without native-run and used cordova instead with the flag --no-native-run.
The command that worked for me:

```
ionic cordova run ios -l --address=0.0.0.0 --no-native-run
```

Answer (score 2):

So native-run seems buggy.

But in fact in ionic-cli, you can pass a param to use cordova instead of native-run and it's work :

```
ionic cordova run ios --no-native-run
```

My personal command :

```
ionic cordova run ios --livereload --consolelogs --buildFlag='-UseModernBuildSystem=0'  --external --no-native-run
```

Answer (score 1):

Try commenting

```
     if (isLockdownErrorResponse(resp)) {
         throw new Error(resp.Error);
     }
```

inside the file

> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/native-run/node_modules/node-ioslib/dist/lockdown.js

It worked for me

Comment: I will try that out soon, but this is not an ideal solution long term.

Comment: the folder ```/node-ioslib/``` does not exist for me

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem. According to this post https://github.com/ios-control/ios-deploy/issues/469 an update to ios-deploy 1.11.2 should solve the problem. I've tried it, multiple times + reinstalling Xcode and other options but nothing works. I am curious if an update to ios-deploy will work for you, so let me know please!

Comment: I tried upgrading to 1.11.2. Installed it via homebrew, updated XCode command line tools etc. but the error also still remains for me.

Comment: Ok, same for me. I don't understand how others have solved this. In the meantime, I will try a fresh ionic project and try to deploy it via cli and see if the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

you need to build it with Xcode and then try running ionic cli again
For some reason that fixes it for me